# Formula for Riemann tensor in 2D

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature

I know that in 2D the Riemann tensor can be expressed in terms of the Ricci scalar as:

$$R_{abcd}=\frac{R}{2}(g_{ac}g_{bd}-g_{ad}g_{bc}).$$

And I see that one can argue this by saying that the combination of g written has the symmetry properties of the Riemann tensor they must be proportional (because in 2d the Riemann tensor has 1 independent component), and the constant of proportionality is determined by contracting the indices.

Now, I was wondering if one could derive this formula explicitly starting from the definition of the ricci scalar in terms of the Riemann tensor and inverting it.

I tried to write  $R=g^{\sigma \rho}g^{\mu \alpha}R_{\alpha \rho \mu \sigma}$. Then to invert it I multiply by the metric two times both sides to get $R g_{\epsilon \sigma}g_{\eta \mu}=R_{\eta \epsilon \mu \sigma}$ which is not what I want. Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot "invert" a scalar equation to get a tensor equation.

Comment: You can not due to the previous comment but you could write out both of the equations for a general 2D diagonal metric explicitly and compare the two results